# BluetoothDevice.ACTION_NAME_CHANGED on a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

How can I manage the **BluetoothDevice.ACTION_NAME_CHANGED** on a *BroadcastReceiver*. I'm familiarized with the *BluetoothChat* example.

---Edit---

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            setTitle(R.string.select_device);
            if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I would like to implement BluetoothDevice.ACTION_NAME_CHANGED but I don't know how

Comment: I'm not understanding specifically what you want to do. As long as you're registered for the broadcast, you would handle it like the other actions.

Comment: I've a ListView and when I start discovering, sometimes the device was shown as "null+bt_address" and after a few seconds adds another device with "name_device+bt_address" with the same "bt_address".

I tried with something like the example above but i couldn't get it work. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had a same problem.
I fixed it.

in onCreate, add below:

```
filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_NAME_CHANGED);
this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

And next, edit BroadcastReceiver below:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Log.d("mReceiver","ACTION_FOUND:"+device.getAddress()+" :"+device.getName());
            // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already

            if(device.getName()==null)
            { //when name is null, skip
              //But if you want to make lists asap, comment out this block.
            }
            else
            {
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    //mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                    boolean listed = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                        String info = mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getItem(i);
                        String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
                        if (device.getAddress().equals(address)) {
                            Log.d("mReceiver", "ACTION_FOUND: replace the item of lists");
                            mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.remove(info);
                            info = device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress();
                            mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.insert(info, i);
                            listed = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(listed==false)
                    {//if it is new device( not in lists), add it.
                        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                    }
                }
            }

        }else if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_NAME_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Log.d("mReceiver", "NAME_CHANGED:" + device.getAddress() + " :" + device.getName());
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                boolean listed = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    String info = mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getItem(i);
                    String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
                    if (device.getAddress().equals(address)) {
                        Log.d("mReceiver", "NAME_CHANGED: replace the item of lists");
                        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.remove(info);
                        info = device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress();
                        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.insert(info, i);
                        listed = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(listed==false)
                {//if it is new device( not in lists), add it.
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
            }
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            setTitle(R.string.select_device);
            if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
            }
        }
    }
};
```